# Google Chrome Untitled tab group icons size

Tags: google-chrome

I updated recently and suddenly untitled chrome tab groups are nearly twice the size they were before.  Is there a way to revert this or change this?  It takes up twice as much space.

Thanks

I couldn't find anything in the changelogs or flags that related.